Out-of-sample forecasting
I have fitted a 3-variable VAR model in Stata and I am looking for a way to make a prediction for the next time step t+1 but I am having some trouble. The model I fit is
var dlinvestment dlincome dlconsumption, lags(1/2)

and I am trying to use predict but I can manage to make it predict for t+1. So far I tried
predict dlinv_fcast, dyn
predict dlinv_fcast, nstep(1)


but none of these work. I just want to predict for dlinvestment.
Any idea on how to do that?
